# Rails 4, SQLite 3: Acts as Votable - Sort for upvotes last week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'd like to display the most upvoted items from the last 7 days.
That way I am able to get the most upvoted items (all time):

```
@items = Item.all.order(cached_votes_up: :desc)
```

item.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    acts_as_votable

end
```

Is there a way to get the most upvoted Items during the last week?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this based on what I remembered when I used the gem a while ago.

You have two tables, `items` and `votes`, votes are created by default if a `acts_as_votable` gem is used.

To join the both the table together 
`@join_table = Item.joins('INNER JOIN votes ON votes.votable_id = items.id')`

//I have not used `cached_votes_up` when I used the gem. I have no idea what does it store and what is it for. If it works, continue below.

After you joined the table, now we need to filter out the item that are rated for the past 7 days. 
`@filter_table = @join_table.order(cached_votes_up: :desc).where(:updated_at => 7.day.ago..Time.now)`

You may need to modify slightly as I do not have the exact table attributes.
Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: I don't know, but as far as I understand that code it just searches for items which got at least one upvote in the past seven days and then orders these by their all-time upvotes. Instead I only want to count the upvotes made in the past week. Please let me know if I am wrong. :-)

Comment: @Gugubaight If you want to calculate it, you should use `count`. Then it will return the counted value for the past 7 days.

Comment: That does not work, because then I get an integer but I want to get the sorted objects so that I can loop through them

Comment: I think I finally get what you are trying to do. You have two tables, `items` and `votes` table since you are using `Acts_as_Votable` gem (`votes` table is generated by the gem). You are trying to find which item has the most votes in the past 7 days. In this case, you have to join both `items` and `votes` table to get the item. Do I get what you are trying to do right?

Comment: Yay! That's exactly the case :)

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if it works. It is all out from what I remembered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125948/discussion-between-melvin-chng-and-gugubaight).